# Query product title or slug based on shortcode atts name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

I would like to query a product by it's title or name (slug). The code below will allow me to retrieve a product with a specific tag, however when I attempt to use `page` or `pagename` instead of `product_tag`, no products are returned. I did not see a relevant `product_page` or similar available unless I have overlooked it. Appreciate insight into where I may have gone wrong.

```
function woo_products_by_name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

        // Get attributes
        extract(shortcode_atts(array( "tags" => '' ), $atts));

        ob_start();
        // Define Query Arguments
        $args = array(
                                //'post_type'    => array('product','product_variation'),
                                'post_type'    => 'product',
                                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                                'product_tag'    => $tags
                                );

        // Create the new query
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        // Get products number
        $product_count = $loop->post_count;

        // If results
        if( $product_count > 0 ) :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

For querying products by their **slug** use **`"name"`** argument or by their **title** use **`"title"`** argument:

```
function woo_products_by_name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // Get attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'tags' => '',
        'name' => ''
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts ));

    ob_start();

    // Define Query Arguments
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'product_tag'    => $tag,
        'name'           => $name,
        'title'          => $title
    ) );

    // Get products number
    $product_count = $loop->post_count;

    // Test raw output
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($loop->posts); echo '</pre>';
```

Tested and works

Official documentation: [WP_query - Post and page parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Comment: Yes, looks like there may be something else wrong as the same product is being returned whether the `title` or `name` is used. I saw this before and assumed I was doing something wrong. Assume defining it in a plug-in verse functions.php should not make a difference.

Comment: If you query a product title using "name" it works because the title is sanitized internally with `sanitize_title_for_query()` function, may be that's why. If the plublished answer is answering your question, please don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks.